# Magento 2 : how to get customer id on observer?

Tags: magento-2.1

I need customer id on my observer, but it is giving error on page load.
My code is:

```
<?php

namespace //..\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class AddressObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    public function execute( Observer $observer ) {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $Id = $customer->getId();       
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls sahre Observer event in question?

Comment: please confirm whether you are using this event customer_register_success ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies but i got the solution using session. By the way I was using customer_address_save_after event.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide what kind of event you are using. If your event dispatch the param called `customer`, you have lost the `getEvent()`,try to use this code below:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

instead of:

```
$observer->getCustomer();
```

Comment: its worked for me